# Calculator - setText(String) doesn't work with Doubles

Tags: java, string, jframe, value-of

So I am trying to make a calculator and I am using JFrame code and trying to use the built in Math to find the square root of a number. The code below is where I am having issues. "display.setText(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));"

gives me the error of "The method setText(String) in the type JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (double)"

```
    sqrt = new JButton("SQRT");
    sqrt.setBounds(298, 141, 65, 65);
    sqrt.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    sqrt.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    sqrt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setTempFirst(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            display.setText(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
            operation[5] = true;

        }
    });
    add(sqrt);
```

Comment: [`NumberFormater.getNumberInstance().format(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since Math.sqrt returns a double you can not do:

```
display.setText(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
```

instead you can use the value returned by that method and use the `String.valueOf()` like:

```
display.setText(String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(....
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this method is expecting String instead of double, so you should convert result of

`Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()))`

to double, eg:

`String.valueOf(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())))`

or

`Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()))+""`

Better way will be formatting this result to some decimal places, eg:

`String.format( "%.2f", YOUR_NUMBER )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
display.setText(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())));
```

should be

```
display.setText(Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText())).toString());
```

Because you need String representation of sqrt. setText() cannot take `Double`

Comment: `Math.sqrt` returns primitive, so it doesn't have a `toString` method, which I'd consider poor practice anyway, given the alternatives